# Activiti 6 sometime waits 5 minutes before starting async process instance

Tags: java, activiti

Activiti 6.0.0 (with spring boot) holds async process and does not start it immediately, when I issue the process starting command:
(There is an open JPA transaction when issuing this command, and entity passed to the process as a variable)

```
ProcessInstance processInstance = runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey(processId, variableMap);
```

After 5 minutes it runs it without any errors.

**LOG:**

```
15:17:01.158 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-5] c.m.i.e.p.input.impl.ImportingPortImpl   : Starting workflow process... [workflowName=batch-main]
<5 MINUTE TEA BREAK>
15:22:10.677 DEBUG [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-6] c.m.i.e.i.c.analizers.ContentAnalizers   : Task really started..
```

This happens about 30% of the cases, in other case it starts immediately, so this is very wierd.

**How to fix this to run immediately in every case** without waiting a 5 minute timeout?

**MORE DETAILED LOG:**

```
16:53:14.136 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] c.m.i.e.r.a.i.IntellivectorImportAdapter : Getting content stream from multipart [multipartIndex=0;fileName=IMPORTED-4e578b1a-e7f6-4b5a-91d0-9e9a40f3328e.tiff;contentType=image/tiff]

16:53:14.137 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : begin
16:53:14.138  INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-2] jdbc.sqlonly                             : select count(RES.ID_) from ACT_RE_PROCDEF RES WHERE RES.KEY_ = 'batch-main' 
16:53:14.142  INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-2] jdbc.sqlonly                             : select nextval ('iv_batch_id_seq') 
16:53:14.144  INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-2] jdbc.sqlonly                             : select nextval ('iv_document_id_seq') 
16:53:14.147  INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-2] jdbc.sqlonly                             : insert into iv_batch (created_date, id) values ('11/28/2017 16:53:14.142', 1245) 
16:53:14.148  INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-2] jdbc.sqlonly                             : insert into iv_document (batch_id, created_date, id) values (1245, '11/28/2017 16:53:14.144', 1272) 
16:53:14.150  INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-2] jdbc.sqlonly                             : insert into iv_document_contents (mime_type, storage_id, document_id, phase) values ('image/tiff', 'c74d06ef-3c92-4c22-8238-7e45e80d53e3', 1272, 'IMPORTED') 
16:53:14.150  INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-2] jdbc.sqlonly                             : update iv_document_contents set index_=0 where document_id=1272 and phase='IMPORTED' 

16:53:14.151 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] c.m.i.e.p.input.impl.ImportingPortImpl   : Imported a batch, starting workflow... [batchId=1245;documentCount=1;workflowName=batch-main]
16:53:14.151  INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-2] jdbc.sqlonly                             : select * from ACT_RE_PROCDEF where KEY_ = 'batch-main' and (TENANT_ID_ = '' or TENANT_ID_ is null) and VERSION_ = (select max(VERSION_) from ACT_RE_PROCDEF where KEY_ = 'batch-main' and (TENANT_ID_ = '' or TENANT_ID_ is null)) 
16:53:14.153  INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-2] jdbc.sqlonly                             : insert into ACT_HI_VARINST (ID_, PROC_INST_ID_, EXECUTION_ID_, TASK_ID_, NAME_, REV_, VAR_TYPE_, BYTEARRAY_ID_, DOUBLE_, LONG_ , TEXT_, TEXT2_, CREATE_TIME_, LAST_UPDATED_TIME_) 
values ( '5048', '5047', '5047', NULL, 'batchId', 0, 'long', NULL, NULL, 1245, '1245', NULL, '11/28/2017 16:53:14.153', '11/28/2017 16:53:14.153' ) 

16:53:14.154  INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-2] jdbc.sqlonly                             : insert into ACT_HI_PROCINST ( ID_, PROC_INST_ID_, BUSINESS_KEY_, PROC_DEF_ID_, START_TIME_, END_TIME_, DURATION_, START_USER_ID_, START_ACT_ID_, END_ACT_ID_, SUPER_PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID_, DELETE_REASON_, TENANT_ID_, NAME_ ) 
values ( '5047', '5047', NULL, 'batch-main:3:5021', '11/28/2017 16:53:14.152', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'theStart', NULL, NULL, NULL, '', NULL ) 
16:53:14.156  INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-2] jdbc.sqlonly                             : insert into ACT_RU_EXECUTION (ID_, REV_, PROC_INST_ID_, BUSINESS_KEY_, PROC_DEF_ID_, ACT_ID_, IS_ACTIVE_, IS_CONCURRENT_, IS_SCOPE_,IS_EVENT_SCOPE_, IS_MI_ROOT_, PARENT_ID_, SUPER_EXEC_, ROOT_PROC_INST_ID_, SUSPENSION_STATE_, TENANT_ID_, NAME_, START_TIME_, START_USER_ID_, IS_COUNT_ENABLED_, EVT_SUBSCR_COUNT_, TASK_COUNT_, JOB_COUNT_, TIMER_JOB_COUNT_, SUSP_JOB_COUNT_, DEADLETTER_JOB_COUNT_, VAR_COUNT_, ID_LINK_COUNT_) 
values ('5047', 1, '5047', NULL, 'batch-main:3:5021', NULL, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, '5047', 1, '', NULL, '11/28/2017 16:53:14.152', NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) , ('5049', 1, '5047', NULL, 'batch-main:3:5021', 'theStart', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, '5047', NULL, '5047', 1, '', NULL, '11/28/2017 16:53:14.153', NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) 
16:53:14.157  INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-2] jdbc.sqlonly                             : insert into ACT_RU_VARIABLE (ID_, REV_, TYPE_, NAME_, PROC_INST_ID_, EXECUTION_ID_, TASK_ID_, BYTEARRAY_ID_, DOUBLE_, LONG_ , TEXT_, TEXT2_) 
values ( '5048', 1, 'long', 'batchId', '5047', '5047', NULL, NULL, NULL, 1245, '1245', NULL ) 
16:53:14.159  INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-2] jdbc.sqlonly                             : insert into ACT_RU_JOB ( ID_, REV_, TYPE_, LOCK_OWNER_, LOCK_EXP_TIME_, EXCLUSIVE_, EXECUTION_ID_, PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID_, PROC_DEF_ID_, RETRIES_, EXCEPTION_STACK_ID_, EXCEPTION_MSG_, DUEDATE_, REPEAT_, HANDLER_TYPE_, HANDLER_CFG_, TENANT_ID_) 
values ('5050', 1, 'message', 'e53309f8-8780-4849-be82-c9acfbffa338', '11/28/2017 16:58:14.153', 1, '5049', '5047', 'batch-main:3:5021', 3, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'async-continuation', NULL, '' ) 

    16:53:14.160 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : begin
    16:53:14.160 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : committing
16:53:14.160 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : committing


16:53:14.161 DEBUG [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-2] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : begin
16:53:14.161  INFO [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-2] jdbc.sqlonly                             : select * from ACT_RU_EXECUTION where ID_ = '5049' 

16:53:14.161 DEBUG [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-2] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : committing
16:53:14.162 DEBUG [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-2] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : begin
16:53:14.162  INFO [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-2] jdbc.sqlonly                             : select * from ACT_RU_JOB where ID_ = '5050' 

16:53:14.163 DEBUG [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-2] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : committing
16:53:14.163 DEBUG [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-2] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : begin
16:53:14.163  INFO [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-2] jdbc.sqlonly                             : select * from ACT_RU_EXECUTION where ID_ = '5047' 

16:53:14.164 DEBUG [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-2] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : committing
16:53:22.492 DEBUG [activiti-acquire-async-jobs] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : begin
16:53:22.493  INFO [activiti-acquire-async-jobs] jdbc.sqlonly                             : select RES.* from ACT_RU_JOB RES where LOCK_EXP_TIME_ is null LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0 

16:53:22.493 DEBUG [activiti-acquire-timer-jobs] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : begin
16:53:22.493 DEBUG [activiti-acquire-async-jobs] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : committing
16:53:22.493  INFO [activiti-acquire-timer-jobs] jdbc.sqlonly                             : select RES.* from ACT_RU_TIMER_JOB RES where DUEDATE_ <= '11/28/2017 16:53:22.493' and LOCK_OWNER_ is null LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0 

16:53:22.495 DEBUG [activiti-acquire-timer-jobs] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : committing
16:53:22.495 DEBUG [activiti-acquire-timer-jobs] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : begin
16:53:22.495 DEBUG [activiti-acquire-timer-jobs] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : committing

<NOT STARTED.... >
```

Alfresco thread: [Async Job Executor only executes job after lock expiration](https://community.alfresco.com/thread/233559-async-job-executor-only-executes-job-after-lock-expiration)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Activiti, but one explanation is that the main thread of Activiti uses the commonly used pattern of waking every 5 minutes (probably using `@Scheduled`) to check if anything needs running, rather than firing the task immediately. Or it may be waiting for another currently running task to complete before firing your task due to being configured to execute sequentially rather than in parallel.

Comment: No, there is no other tasks, and in the other case it runs immediately, not in  a random timeout between 0-5 minutes. For me it seems the timeout is the task timeout , for long running tasks assuming it is broken and it tries to run it again, so seems Activiti thinks the task is running, and it tries it again after 5 mintutes.

Comment: Can you post your process xml schema? And can you confirm after starting process that it really did not start immediately? Like `Log.info("Number of process instances: " + runtimeService.createProcessInstanceQuery().count());`

Comment: what's more  `16:53:14.151 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] c.m.i.e.p.input.impl.ImportingPortImpl   : Imported a batch, starting workflow... ` When is this printed? (befiore or after process is started) Are you executing any batch queries before starting process?

Comment: @CrazySabbath: Before.  Yes there are restart events on startup before this, that triggers again some waiting tasks to load something to a runtime buisness component, but those seems to be finished properly much earlier in separate transaction.

Comment: @DanielHári Can you post your schema or at least start element? What restart events? Are you sure they are no causing the delay? Why don't you try disabling them, that would make it clear if they are causing this delay.

Comment: This is the workflow: https://codeshare.io/5e0EnJ

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160013/discussion-between-daniel-hari-and-crazysabbath).

Comment: It seems in the log, the job is locked: "LOCK_EXP_TIME_", but why if it is the only job?

Answer (score 2):

I've narrowed this down to this issue: Tasks that have ‘Asynchronous’ checked and ‘Exclusive’ unchecked cause the delay. I created a workflow that showcases the behavior. Five tasks that each sleep for one sec and have various combinations of the ‘Asynchronous’ and 'Exclusive' flags set. In the log snippet below, notice the 5-min delay before task 'scripttask04_async' as well as the error message logged by ExecuteAsyncJobCmd.

```
engine 17:25:48.337 DEBUG NfExecutionListener            execution id: 60065, received event: start, task id: null, parent id: null, variables {admin=null}, local variables {admin=VariableInstanceEntity[id=60066, name=admin, type=null]}
engine 17:25:48.396 DEBUG ExecuteAsyncJobCmd             Executing async job 60068
engine 17:25:48.407 DEBUG NfExecutionListener            execution id: 60065, received event: start, task id: null, parent id: null, variables {admin=null}, local variables {admin=VariableInstanceEntity[id=60066, name=admin, type=null]}
engine 17:25:48.407 DEBUG ContinueProcessOperation       Executing activityBehavior class org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.NoneStartEventActivityBehavior on activity 'debugHelperStart' with execution 60067
engine 17:25:48.411 DEBUG TakeOutgoingSequenceFlowsOperation Leaving flow node class org.activiti.bpmn.model.StartEvent with id 'debugHelperStart' by following it's 1 outgoing sequenceflow
engine 17:25:48.413 DEBUG ContinueProcessOperation       Sequence flow 'flow1' encountered. Continuing process by following it using execution 60067
engine 17:25:48.414 DEBUG ContinueProcessOperation       Executing activityBehavior class org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.ScriptTaskActivityBehavior on activity 'debugHelper01Task_sync_excl' with execution 60067
 ==========================  ===   ==== before sleep debugHelper01Task_sync_excl
engine 17:25:49.308 INFO  AnnotationConfigApplicationContext Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@40b5162b: startup date [Tue May 01 17:25:49 UTC 2018]; parent: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3439f68d
engine 17:25:49.407 INFO  AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
engine 17:25:49.843 INFO  ChainedDynamicProperty         Flipping property: localhost.ribbon.ActiveConnectionsLimit to use NEXT property: niws.loadbalancer.availabilityFilteringRule.activeConnectionsLimit = 2147483647
 ==========================  ===   ==== after sleep debugHelper01Task_sync_excl
engine 17:25:49.851 DEBUG TakeOutgoingSequenceFlowsOperation Leaving flow node class org.activiti.bpmn.model.ScriptTask with id 'debugHelper01Task_sync_excl' by following it's 1 outgoing sequenceflow
engine 17:25:49.851 DEBUG ContinueProcessOperation       Sequence flow 'flow2' encountered. Continuing process by following it using execution 60067
engine 17:25:49.960 INFO  BaseLoadBalancer               Client: localhost instantiated a LoadBalancer: DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{NFLoadBalancer:name=localhost,current list of Servers=[],Load balancer stats=Zone stats: {},Server stats: []}ServerList:null
engine 17:25:49.974 INFO  DynamicServerListLoadBalancer  Using serverListUpdater PollingServerListUpdater
engine 17:25:49.986 INFO  DynamicServerListLoadBalancer  DynamicServerListLoadBalancer for client localhost initialized: DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{NFLoadBalancer:name=localhost,current list of Servers=[],Load balancer stats=Zone stats: {},Server stats: []}ServerList:com.netflix.loadbalancer.ConfigurationBasedServerList@50af6398
engine 17:25:59.119 DEBUG ExecuteAsyncJobCmd             Executing async job 60072
engine 17:25:59.122 DEBUG ContinueProcessOperation       Executing activityBehavior class org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.ScriptTaskActivityBehavior on activity 'scripttask02_async_excl' with execution 60067
 ==========================  ===   ==== before sleep scripttask02_async_excl
 ==========================  ===   ==== after sleep scripttask02_async_excl
engine 17:26:00.132 DEBUG TakeOutgoingSequenceFlowsOperation Leaving flow node class org.activiti.bpmn.model.ScriptTask with id 'scripttask02_async_excl' by following it's 1 outgoing sequenceflow
engine 17:26:00.132 DEBUG ContinueProcessOperation       Sequence flow 'flow3' encountered. Continuing process by following it using execution 60067
engine 17:26:00.132 DEBUG ContinueProcessOperation       Executing activityBehavior class org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.ScriptTaskActivityBehavior on activity 'scripttask03_sync' with execution 60067
 ==========================  ===   ==== before sleep scripttask03_sync
 ==========================  ===   ==== after sleep scripttask03_sync
engine 17:26:01.136 DEBUG TakeOutgoingSequenceFlowsOperation Leaving flow node class org.activiti.bpmn.model.ScriptTask with id 'scripttask03_sync' by following it's 1 outgoing sequenceflow
engine 17:26:01.136 DEBUG ContinueProcessOperation       Sequence flow 'flow4' encountered. Continuing process by following it using execution 60067
engine 17:26:01.148 DEBUG ExecuteAsyncJobCmd             Job does not exist anymore and will not be executed. It has most likely been deleted as part of another concurrent part of the process instance.
engine 17:31:39.388 DEBUG ExecuteAsyncJobCmd             Executing async job 60076
engine 17:31:39.392 DEBUG ContinueProcessOperation       Executing activityBehavior class org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.ScriptTaskActivityBehavior on activity 'scripttask04_async' with execution 60067
 ==========================  ===   ==== before sleep scripttask04_async
 ==========================  ===   ==== after sleep scripttask04_async
engine 17:31:40.401 DEBUG TakeOutgoingSequenceFlowsOperation Leaving flow node class org.activiti.bpmn.model.ScriptTask with id 'scripttask04_async' by following it's 1 outgoing sequenceflow
engine 17:31:40.402 DEBUG ContinueProcessOperation       Sequence flow 'flow5' encountered. Continuing process by following it using execution 60067
engine 17:31:40.422 DEBUG ExecuteAsyncJobCmd             Executing async job 60078
engine 17:31:40.425 DEBUG ContinueProcessOperation       Executing activityBehavior class org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.ScriptTaskActivityBehavior on activity 'scripttask05_async_excl' with execution 60067
 ==========================  ===   ==== before sleep scripttask05_async_excl
 ==========================  ===   ==== after sleep scripttask05_async_excl
engine 17:31:41.440 DEBUG TakeOutgoingSequenceFlowsOperation Leaving flow node class org.activiti.bpmn.model.ScriptTask with id 'scripttask05_async_excl' by following it's 1 outgoing sequenceflow
engine 17:31:41.441 DEBUG ContinueProcessOperation       Sequence flow 'flow6' encountered. Continuing process by following it using execution 60067
engine 17:31:41.441 DEBUG ContinueProcessOperation       Executing activityBehavior class org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.NoneEndEventActivityBehavior on activity 'debugHelperEnd' with execution 60067
engine 17:31:41.441 DEBUG TakeOutgoingSequenceFlowsOperation Leaving flow node class org.activiti.bpmn.model.EndEvent with id 'debugHelperEnd' by following it's 0 outgoing sequenceflow
engine 17:31:41.441 DEBUG TakeOutgoingSequenceFlowsOperation No outgoing sequence flow found for flow node 'debugHelperEnd'.
engine 17:31:41.476 DEBUG NfExecutionListener            execution id: 60065, received event: end, task id: null, parent id: null, variables {admin=null}, local variables {admin=VariableInstanceEntity[id=60066, name=admin, type=null]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm suspecting the open transaction in combination with the `ExecuteAsyncJobCmd` are what cause this issue. From the codebase of the command:

```
// We need to refetch the job, as it could have been deleted by another concurrent job
// For exampel: an embedded subprocess with a couple of async tasks and a timer on the boundary of the subprocess
// when the timer fires, all executions and thus also the jobs inside of the embedded subprocess are destroyed.
// However, the async task jobs could already have been fetched and put in the queue.... while in reality they have been deleted. 
// A refetch is thus needed here to be sure that it exists for this transaction.

Job job = commandContext.getJobEntityManager().findById(jobId);
if (job == null) {
  log.debug("Job does not exist anymore and will not be executed. It has most likely been deleted "
      + "as part of another concurrent part of the process instance.");
  return null;
}
```

This is the exact behaviour we are experiencing while testing with an in-memory db and async jobs, using the default process engine configuration provided in the Activiti Spring Boot Starter.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I wanted to know exactly why this was happening, so I dug into the source code of Activiti 6.0.

It turns out this is a concurrency bug, which has to do with transaction handling and which happens specifically if you use activiti-spring.

See issue on GitHub here: https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/issues/2666

Specifically, when a job causes another job to be created, there is a possibility that Activiti's async executor starts executing the job before the transaction that inserts the job entity in the database, has committed. This happens specifically with activiti-spring because of the way commands are executed and the transaction wrapping is done.

I currently do not have a good workaround for this (one way to avoid it is to not use activiti-spring, but that's not feasible if you need the Spring integration in your application).

Answer (score 0):

As Jesper said, the root cause of the problem is that the job is submitted to the executor service before the transaction is committed and the method  **commandContext.getJobEntityManager().findById(jobId);** will return null :

```
Job job = commandContext.getJobEntityManager().findById(jobId);
if (job == null) {
  log.debug("Job does not exist anymore and will not be executed. It has most likely been deleted "
      + "as part of another concurrent part of the process instance.");
  return null;
}
```

This problem does not occur with Message Queue based Async Executor because the message is sent to the queue after the commit.